# How to build the Layout from the Properties frame in QtDesigner?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

How can I build the Layout used by QtCreator in Tools->Options for my own application? It should look like this, but with another content:

[image: QtCreator Tools->Options]

How can I do this using C++/Qt using the QtDesigner integrated in QtCreator?

Comment: A `QListView` or `QListWidget` will do the trick.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks it works, but how can I control the size of the items in a `QListView` using a `QStringListModel`?

Comment: Look at `QHeaderView::setMinimumSectionSize`, for example. You should also do the "obvious" thing: compile Qt Creator, run it under a debugger, and see how it manages the option page list. IIRC it's done in the core plugin.

Comment: @KubaOber I actually want to use a `QListView` and not a `QHeaderView`, is that possible?

Comment: If you want a list without headers, sure. You'll need the model to provide item size hints through the `SizeHintRole`. I don't know if the string list model retains such data. If it doesn't, it'd be a trivial matter to subclass it and provide data for this role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution! I needed to use a `QListView` with a `QStringListModel` in it. To set the Item Size and Icons manually, I needed to subclass `QStringListModel` and `QStyledItemDelegate`:

```
// ItemDelegate to set item size manually
class MyItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    virtual QSize sizeHint (const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QSize suggestion = QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index);
        return QSize(suggestion.width(), 30);
    }
};

// StringListModel to allow setting images
class MyStringListModel : public QStringListModel
{
public:
    virtual QVariant data (const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        if (role == Qt::DecorationRole)
        {
            QString value = stringList().at(index.row());
            if (value == "new")
                return add;
            else
                return db;
        }
        else
            return QStringListModel::data(index, role);
    }

private:
    QIcon db = QIcon::fromTheme("server-database");
    QIcon add = QIcon::fromTheme("list-add");
};
```

Then, I could update my `QListView` (that was created by Qt):

```
MyStringListModel * model = new MyStringListModel();
model->setStringList(QStringList() << "test" << "new");
ui->databases->setModel(model);
ui->databases->setItemDelegate(new MyItemDelegate());
```